# Selenium Java > Unable to select/ click element from menu content. (Fetching seventh element on clicking)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck in the middle of a process.

I have to click on the 7th element of the menu content.
These element are displayed after clicking on [image]

i am able to click on this and elements are being displayed but not able to click the element within the block.

Do provide your suggestion. I want to click Template.

[image]

Comment: In which platform? DO you have a URL for us to check it??

Comment: Hi I am using Apache Nifi  and running on localhost.